# No me imprime el valor aun habiendo usado el tipo correcto

Tags: java

Este es mi codigo de java, estoy comenzando y estamos dando los tipos de variables y como usarlos. Nos piden un programa con un determinado comportamiento, mi pregunta es porque ganancia es 0 si lo declare como double e interes como entero? Notese que dejo interes como entero para que no introduzcan valores con decimales

```
package tema_2_2;

public class Ej_8 {

/*
    Si  un banco  nos  paga  el  7%  de intereses  e ingresamos  4000  euros.  ¿Cuánto 
    ganaremos  después  de  un  año?.  ¿Qué  importe  final  tendremos  en  el  banco  al  final 
    del año?
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    double dinero_i = 4000;
    int interes = 7;
    double ganancia = dinero_i * (interes / 100);
    double dinero_f = dinero_i + ganancia;
    
    System.out.println("Hemos ganado " +ganancia+ " euros y ahora tenemos " +dinero_f+ " euros");

    }

}
```

Comment: un entero dividido entre otro entero el resultado será otro entero; si el numerador es menor que el denominador el resultado será 0; entonces si un número multiplicas por 0 será 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando divides 2 números enteros el resultado será un número entero y cuando el numerador es menor que el denominador el resultado será 0. por eso cuando divides interes/100 te da 0

```
int a=4;
int b=5;
System.out.println(a/b);
//La salida será 0
```

Si queremos que nos muestre el resultado en decimales tenemos que hacer un cast ya sea al numerador o denominador

```
int a=4;
int b=5;
System.out.println((double)a/b);
//La salida será 0.8
```

Comment: Ya lo solucione, poniendo 100.0 me lo toma correctamente, lo unico es que si pongo 100f, añade unos decimales al resultado que no se de donde salen

Comment: Esto  se debe a que la computadora realiza los cálculos en binario por ello está en nosotros como queremos mostrar los resultados obtenidos.